# click to scroller, need a few pixels added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experimenting with a nav that takes you to the section with a smooth scroll, it works really well but I have a sticky nav which covers the section heading. So i need to add about 40 pixels to the top of each section when clicked.

What do I need to add

```
           $('#about-me').click( function() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.about-me').offset().top  
                }, 900);
            });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will do the math for you by taking the height of navigation menu.

```
$('#about-me').click( function() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.about-me').offset().top-$('#navigation').height()  
                }, 900);
            });
```